# Insert SQL query results into separate PHP variables

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to make an ad system with PHP pdo. How can I get result id's of the following SQL query into my PHP variables?

```
SELECT id FROM ads, ( SELECT id AS sid FROM ads WHERE position="A" ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 5 ) tmp WHERE ads.id = tmp.sid
```

I just don't know how to get those values in the variables like this:

```
$ad_1 = result[1]
$ad_2 = result[2]
$ad_3 = result[3]
$ad_4 = result[4]
$ad_5 = result[5]
```

With the help of those variables ($ad_1...5) I could display unique and random ads in different places, get correct data, and update ad clicks/views...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to get into the habit of using prepared statements like this:

```
<?php
$adIds = array();
$position = 'A'; // probably set dynamicaly
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM ads, ( SELECT id AS sid FROM ads WHERE position=? ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 5 ) tmp WHERE ads.id = tmp.sid");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $position);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $adIds[] = $row[0];
  }
}
?>
```

`$adIds` is now an array containing all the ids returned from the select statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer!  
  
I was able to get first row into variable, but not the second ->. 
bindParam needed to be a variable. After the prepare I put it like this:  
`$stmt->bindParam(1, $position); // or use a variable  
if ($stmt->execute()) {  
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {  
    $ad1 = $row[0];  
    $ad2 = $row[1];  
  }  
}  
`

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing.  Let me see if I can make my example a little more clear.

Comment: Does that make more sense now?

Comment: Thank you so much Casey, got it working now. It was easier to understand after you made the update. 

I appreaciate your help a lot! :)

Comment: Absolutely! I wasn't able to upvote, because I don't have enough reputation. Just found a way to accept the right answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$begin = "ad_";
for($i = 0; $i < 6 ; $i++) {
    $($begin.$i) = $result[$i];
}
```

(assuming you array `$result` is previously defined)

Comment: Thanks for the help too! Casey's answer was more what I was looking for.

Comment: I didn't understood very well your problem. I thought it was about having the result in separated variables not about extracting the values from the driver